# Why does legilimency seem more powerful than before?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

In the Harry Potter books, Severus Snape told Harry the following while teaching him Occlumency:

> "The mind is not a book, to be opened at will and examined at leisure. Thoughts are not etched on the inside of skulls, to be perused by any invader. The mind is a complex and many-layered thing, Potter. Or at least most minds are... It is true, however, that those who have mastered Legilimency are able, under certain conditions, to delve into the minds of their victims and to interpret their findings correctly."

However, in Fantastic Beasts, Queenie is shown possessing an extremely strong ability to read minds, to the point that she can actually read the "sentences" forming in a person's head in real time. Is there a reason for these conflicting portrayals?

Comment: I noted this while watching the movie, also that here job at the ministry seemed to consist of fetching tea which made me wonder if she (aside from the cooking) was commensurately under-skilled or deficient in "regular" magic... she does seem to be written in the roll of damsel in distress.

Comment: "The plot demanded it, Lord Malak"

Comment: @Toby: I guess you meant "role".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit whoops I did indeed. Rolls are tasty too though. Ironic typo considering she loved a baker ;-)

Comment: @Toby: Well, quite :D

Comment: I seem to recall mention somewhere that there are natural-born Legilimens, who have the gift from birth; also that they are much more powerful/skilled with Legilimency than those who are not born with it.

Comment: May be similar to the way in which Polyjuice was introduced as being extremely rare and then ended up being used by every Tom, Dick and (especially) Harry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Queenie's talent is inborn, while others had to learn theirs.

> **Snape says the mind isn't a book to read at leisure. But Queenie seemed to do just that. Love to know more about Legilimency.**
>
> **J.K. Rowling**: *Snape had to train a slight natural ability. Queenie was born with a great talent, though she's not infallible.*
>
> ([Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/811588195309723650))

Also, her skills weren't as great as she was letting on:

> **J.K. Rowling**: While Queenie could read your mind right now, she doesn't always draw the right conclusions from what she's reading. It's like she can constantly hear a tape of what you're thinking, but she's not that good at interpreting it so she still makes mistakes about people. That's just fun to write.
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them DVD: The Goldstein Sisters*</sub>

Answer (score 12):

### Queenie seems to be an unusually powerful Legilimens

Alison Sudol, the actress who portrays Queenie, discussed her character's powers in [a 2016 interview](https://www.pottermore.com/news/fantastic-beasts-alison-sudol-interview-playing-queenie) with Pottermore; what she describes is quite commensurate with Snape's description:

> [S]he sees *into* people. She's not just reading what you're currently thinking, she’s reading you. Being a Legilimens means she's reading your whole story, she's seeing all of your truths.

This was brought up a little more in [an interview with *Entertainment Weekly*](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/08/05/fantastic-beasts-queenie):

> "She's basically a complete and utter magical empath," Sudol tells EW. "She's able to read people — so it's not just reading somebody’s thoughts. She's can *[sic]* read into someone's story, she can see people's goals.

Where Queenie mainly differs is that her Legilimency is more passive than active; that EW article describes her as a "magical antenna", though I'm not sure where they pulled that from.

Comment: It's true that in the movie, she clearly mention that she can't "turn it off" during the scene where she talk with Newt about Leta Lestrange. Maybe that's what they were referencing with the magical antenna analogy.

Comment: When she says _"Being a Legilimens means (…)"_, it suggest it's not specific to her character but to legilimency. This seems to be a case of script writers not taking consistency into account too much.

Comment: Such an useful ability. She couldve been a healer or the next dark lady. Instead,  she serves drinks :/

Comment: @Nowhereman, I disagree. My understanding of that quote is that there are two competing terms: Legilimency and a Legilimens. Legilimens is a spell which allows you to perform Legilimency, which Snape uses on Harry. A Legilimens is a witch/wizard who unconsciously reads people, without use of the Legilimens spell.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard This distinction is not canonical AFAICT. In OotP, Dumbledore says 'I am a sufficiently accomplished Legilimens myself to know when I am being lied to".

Comment: @Nowhereman, I quite agree. Voldemort is also 'the most accomplished legilimens the world has ever seen.' However, from the interview that was quoted on this answer, it seems to me that they are adding an extra depth to the term, especially as none of the book Legilimens' could *read your whole story* yet this character can. Most of Pottermore is considered cannon, and it may be that they are building on the cannon, by making another type of wizard. This would be similar to Tonks, who can do human transfiguration on herself without effort, despite it being very difficult magic.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard Note that Pottermore is a news site as well as a repository for Rowling's writings. An interview with an actress doesn't achieve a special level of canonicity just because it's on Pottermore

Comment: @EvSunWoodard - Being on Pottermore doesn't make something canon. (Otherwise things like the movies and the plays would be canon.) It just happens to be that a lot of Rowling's writings, including her abandoned encyclopedia were hosted by Pottermore.

Comment: @ibid - I know canon is debatable, but how can the movies and plays *not* be canon? Rowling has even said herself that the play is canon. For what it's worth, I also think that EvSunWoodard is thinking at the film intends us to think of Queenie. I think she is meant to have a natural skill (like Tonks) that others (like Snape and Dumbledore) can learn.

Comment: @ThruGog - Yet the general consensus here is that the movies are not canon.

Comment: @JasonBaker &ibid - Yes, I'll agree that parts of Pottermore are not cannon (the parts not written by JK), my point was, as ThruGog pointed out, is that I am making a devil's advocate argument for the Film intention, and the interpretation I got from the actress' quote. The films do not make it cannon, but my point was that I think that THEY are making a distinction between the spell and the innate ability that has previously not been made in the cannon material.

Comment: And as Rowling wrote the script, this film must be the most canon film of all!

Answer (score 6):

Think of it as Tonks being a natural "shapeshifter" (metamorphmagus) and the normal people who have to use spells to transfigurate. Legilimency is the same thing it seems, you have the spell normal people use, and you have the people who have it as a natural gift.